# Integer.parseInt("-1") result an error

Tags: java, android, integer, parseint, negative-number

I'm writing new accounting program for my customer on Android,In some case I need to convert text of EditText to integer,but when I want to parse **"-1"** the `java.lang.NumberFormatException` occured!

for understanding my problem try this:
    **int i = Integer.parseInt("-1");**

Can anybody help me?
Thank you!

**this is code:**

```
  int i = Integer.parseInt("-1");
```

and this is **log trace**:

```
07-09 03:33:36.932: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 03:36:09.252: E/AndroidRuntime(985): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 03:36:09.252: E/AndroidRuntime(985): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "-1 
07-09 03:36:09.252: E/AndroidRuntime(985): "
07-09 03:36:09.252: E/AndroidRuntime(985):  at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
07-09 03:36:09.252: E/AndroidRuntime(985):  at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
07-09 03:36:09.252: E/AndroidRuntime(985):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
07-09 03:36:09.252: E/AndroidRuntime(985):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
07-09 03:36:09.252: E/AndroidRuntime(985):  at forms.FYH_moshtari.UpdateRow(FYH_moshtari.java:149)
07-09 03:36:09.252: E/AndroidRuntime(985):  at yhesabyargui.YMaster_Body.OnAccept(YMaster_Body.java:61)
07-09 03:36:09.252: E/AndroidRuntime(985):  at yhesabyargui.YMaster_Body$10.onClick(YMaster_Body.java:321)
07-09 03:36:09.252: E/AndroidRuntime(985):  at yhesabyargui.CYH_Ctrl_ToolItem.onClick(CYH_Ctrl_ToolItem.java:111)
07-09 03:36:09.252: E/AndroidRuntime(985):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
07-09 03:36:09.252: E/AndroidRuntime(985):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
07-09 03:36:09.252: E/AndroidRuntime(985):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-09 03:36:09.252: E/AndroidRuntime(985):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-09 03:36:09.252: E/AndroidRuntime(985):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

This is complete code:

```
public interface IYH_BodyControl {
void showError(String Caption);
void showHint(String Caption);
void setNormal();
String getValue();
void setValue(String Value);
void setEnable(Boolean Enable);
void setLabel(String Label);
void setVisible(Boolean Visible);
LinearLayout getFrame();
int getID();
Boolean ValidateForInsert();
Boolean ValidateForUpdate();
Boolean ValidateForDelete();
void ClearContent();
void Focus();
}
....
    protected Hashtable<Integer, IYH_BodyControl> ctrls = new Hashtable<Integer, IYH_BodyControl>();
....
protected void InsertRow() {
    tblmoshtari().setAddress(ctrls.get(ctrladdr).getValue());
    tblmoshtari().setFname(ctrls.get(ctrlfname).getValue());
    tblmoshtari().setFamily(ctrls.get(ctrlfamily).getValue());
    tblmoshtari().setMobile(ctrls.get(ctrlmobile).getValue());
    tblmoshtari().setTel(ctrls.get(ctrltel).getValue());
    tblmoshtari().setMaxDebt(Integer.parseInt(ctrls.get(ctrlmaxdebt).getValue()));
    tblmoshtari().Insert();
}
....
```

Is it clear?

Comment: Are you sure that the first character was an ordinary hyphen?  Not an en-dash or some kind of fancy hyphen?

Comment: In addition, can you post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Dear David nothing more,just "-1"!

Comment: Are you using this inside a method of `TextWatcher`?

Comment: @OP I suggest you post the stack trace as [BackSlash](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1759845/backslash) is saying. Maybe your `NFE` happens somewhere else, or there is more to the stack trace. Also a little more code would not hurt.

Comment: Problem is simple Integer.parseInt("-1") doesn't work for me!

Comment: You try parse "-1 07-09 03:36:09.252" not "-1".

Comment: @MiguelAngel_LV That is part of the stack trace, although it could be that the return is passed as well i.e trying to run `Integer.parseInt("-1\n")`

Comment: @Trengot ok, now the stackt trace is correct formated and I see it better.

Comment: No dear @MiguelAngel_LV, there is no other character than "-1"

Comment: @user3819411, There is an extra character (`\n`). When you call `parseInt`, what is the exact line in your code?

Comment: I think the character is a line feed, not a newline. Something like `"-1\r"`

Comment: int i = Integer.parseint("-1"); !!!!

Comment: I don't know why everybody wanna say there is extra character there?

Comment: Try copying that code line to a text-only editor and back to your IDE, see if it still triggers the exception.

Comment: Dear @Mena this problem is actually happen on parsing Integer from EditText,but I've tried this by direct line of code too

Comment: @user3819411 the stacktrace is showing a newline/linefeed in the exception which would explain the NFE. Try using `<text>.trim()`.

Comment: Thanks all,trim() done all!,but there is question for me why java adds additional \r or \n to text?

Comment: It is not java that is adding it, it has been there all along

Comment: What about EditText? I never add any \r or \n to them? but it's still error on parsing?

Comment: We can't conclude anything until you provide the complete code where you are facing the problem. :)

Comment: I've been add code dear

Answer (score 0):

I think the log error shows that there is a space after -one-

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "-1 
 07-09 03:36:09.252: E/AndroidRuntime(985): "
```

it is like

```
 Invalid int: "-1 "
```

I recommend to do

```
 String num = "-1";
 Integer.parseInt(num.trim());
```

Comment: No dear! That was "-1"

Answer (score 0):

Please check the the text to see if it contains any invisible characters like white spaces. Try to trim the text before you convert the text to int. int i = Integer.parseInt("-1"); should work without any issues.